# PowerShell: Or Condition in While Loop

Tags: powershell

I've a really simple problem, but i dont get it working. I have a loop which checks if one of two possible files is existing, if not then sleep and check again in two seconds.

```
while (([System.IO.File]::Exists($terminationFile) -ne $true) -or ([System.IO.File]::Exists($noFile) -ne $true)) {
    # wait 2 seconds and check again
    Start-Sleep -s 2
}
```

If I check both conditions in the same loop it checks only the first one.

Would be great if anybody can help

Regards, 
Justin

Comment: You probably mean: while (!(Test-Path $terminationFile) -and !(Test-Path $noFile)) { Start-Sleep -s 2 }

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. But why is it working when I only check for: while ([System.IO.File]::Exists($terminationFile) -ne $true) ?

Comment: It because if the first check succeeds IE its false then the second check is never run.  If the first check fails then it would check the second.  If you want both checks to succeed before doing anything use -and like David said

Answer (score 3):

An interpretaion of [David Brant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311712/david-brabant) worked for me:

```
while (!(Test-Path -Path $terminationFile) -or !(Test-Path -Path $noFile)) {
    Start-Sleep 2
}
```